# ASPNET/monoDevelop: Create and Deploy a Web Api in monoDevelop

Tags: asp.net, monodevelop, ubuntu-16.04

I am new in monoDevelop.. I installed it in Ubuntu 16.04·
I installed  aspnet for monoDevelop and when I create the new project I only see MVC options. I would like to see WebApi if can be possible.

how can I create a Web Api of ASPNet 5 in monodevelop? 
How can I deploy it too? I have installed mono-xsp but I don't know how can I configure monoDevelop.

Thx

Comment: Which version of Web API do you want? For ASP.NET Core there is a separate Add-in.

Comment: 2.0. I know about that addin, you are right, but how can I deploy it?